# localparameters to make code generic to support different data widths

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, hdl

I am currently designing Verilog logic that is generic so that I can modify the width of registers based on parameters that is being passed as inputs to the module. The parameters are `RWIDTH` and `BWIDTH`. Currently I am testing it for two cases

`RWIDTH=16, BWIDTH=16` and

`RWIDTH=20, BWIDTH=16`

I am having some issues in making the code adapt to different width. Below is a small portion of the code.

```
localparam DIFF = RWIDTH-BWIDTH;
localparam BYTE_LENGTH = 8
localparam ROUND_2_BYTE = BYTE_LENGTH-DIFF;
```

When `RWIDTH=16, BWIDTH=16` , I want `ROUND_2_BYTE` to be equal to  `0`

but when `RWIDTH=20, BWIDTH=16`, I want `ROUND_2_BYTE` to be equal to `4`

Please note that `ROUND_2_BYTE` will be used to calculate further parameters that I have not shown for the sake of simplicity.

How can I achieve this using localparams or any other way in Verilog? I am also interested to hear about other approaches that the above can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a conditional operator.  Change:

```
localparam ROUND_2_BYTE = BYTE_LENGTH-DIFF;
```

to:

```
localparam ROUND_2_BYTE = (DIFF == 0) ? 0 : BYTE_LENGTH-DIFF;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function call to put whatever code you need to set a parameter if you can't fit it into a single equation. The function input arguments must all be constants or other parameters

```
function integer R2B(integer R,B);
  case (1)
  R==16 && B==16: R2B = 0;
  R==20 && B==16: R2B = 4;
  endcase
endfunction

localparam ROUND_2_BYTE = R2B(RWIDTH, BWIDTH);
```